Passing xcom to source_objects parameter in GCSToBigQueryOperator Airflow
I have Airflow DAG with 2 tasks.
First task is list_gcs_files which is defined as following:
    list_gcs_files = PythonOperator(
        task_id='list_gcs_files',
        python_callable=get_file_list,
        op_kwargs={'execution_date': '{{ execution_date }}'},
        provide_context=True,
    )

Python function, list_gcs_files is using, looks like this:
def get_file_list(execution_date, **kwargs):
    bucket_name = 'some-dummy-bucket'
    execution_date = pendulum.parse(execution_date).date()
    prefix = f"customers/{execution_date.strftime('%Y-%m')}-{execution_date.day}/"

    hook = GCSHook(google_cloud_storage_conn_id='google_cloud_default')
    blobs = hook.list(bucket_name=bucket_name, prefix=prefix)

    files = [str(blob) for blob in blobs]

    return files

And the second task is a GCSToBigQueryOperator that should move this data to bronze layer.
    load_to_bronze = GCSToBigQueryOperator(
        task_id='load_to_bronze',
        bucket='some-dummy-bucket',
        source_objects="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='list_gcs_files') }}",
        destination_project_dataset_table='bronze.customers',
        schema_fields=[
              # SOME SCHEMA IS DEFINED HERE
        ],
        source_format='CSV',
        skip_leading_rows=1,
        write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
    )

In the xcom on Airflow for the first task (completes with success) I see the return value, and it looks like this:

['customers/2022-08-2/2022-08-1_part2__customers.csv', 'customers/2022-08-2/2022-08-2_part1__customers.csv']

Second task fails with the following exception:

Source URI must not contain the ',' character: gs://some-dummy-bucket/['customers/2022-08-2/2022-08-1_part2__customers.csv', 'customers/2022-08-2/2022-08-2_part1__customers.csv']

What I tried:
I have changed the type of the returned to xcom data. I was returning string of these file names joined by "," and then in second task I was splitting this string back to list, cause I thought it is data type problem. It didn't help.
Another thing I have tried and it helped is hardcodded source_objects.
when I provide the list from xcom to this parameter manually it is working

source_objects=["customers/2022-08-2/2022-08-1_part2__customers.csv",
"customers/2022-08-2/2022-08-2_part1__customers.csv"]

I don't understand why it doesn't work when the list is taken from xcom.

Because it's being formatted as a string. "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull...}}" is a string. Passing source_objects=list_gcs_files.output instead is a better alternative

Thank you @C.Nivs. It is working. Didn't know we could do it this way.
